# Can I Install packages or softwares to live Ubuntu USB Drive?

Tags: package-management, live-usb

I am using a 160GB HDD installed Windows 7,
and
I want to use Ubuntu Linux temporary in my System, Can I install softwares in the Live USB permanent while using it.
 Like Tor Browser I want it every time when I use my USB stick again and again.

*Any Help is appreciated.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You need to give the live USB a persistent file storage area (called Casper)

Here is a guide
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence

Another alternative is to actually install Ubuntu to your USB disk and run it off that (USB 3.0 or higher is best, and you need a BIOS that will boot it reliably. I've had mixed success with different boxes on this one).