# Can I install Java on a live persistence Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, java, root, persistence

I wanted to know can I install Java and other software on persistence Ubuntu (USB drive).
How can we do that because when I tried sudo apt install default-jdk I got a msg related to dpkg and something that the drive is only read only,?

Help plz

Comment: Probably not worth the hassle (why not use a VM, dual boot or WSL?) but if you really want to do this, you need a live persistent USB. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258486/will-a-live-usb-with-persistence-store-files-automatically) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033850/can-i-install-packages-or-softwares-to-live-ubuntu-usb-drive).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

Comment: If you do a Full install to USB you can do anything that you can do with an install to internal drive, See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step . Welcome to Ask Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the message that the Drive is read only then you probably dont have required permissions to install Java. I think you have made a live USB of Ubuntu instead of a persistant live USB